# 2D mutable iterator/generator

Tags: python, image, iterator, numpy, generator

I have a NxN matrix which I want to split into non-overlap KxK block. For each block, I want to assign new values to the elements.

Since this looks like a good place for a generator, I implemented:

```
def extracted_patches(im, top_left, patch_size, grid_size):
    '''Extract patches in row-major order following a specific configuration

    Parameters
    ----------
    im : the input image (2D numpy array)
    top_left : (y,x) coordinate of the top left point (e.g. (3,5))
    grid_size : (cy, cx) how many patches in the y-direction and in the x-direction
    patch_size : (h, w) how many pixels for the size of each patch

    Returns
    -------
    a generator that goes through each patch (a numpy array view) in row-major order
    '''
    for i in xrange(grid_size[0]):
        for j in xrange(grid_size[1]):
            yield im[top_left[0] + patch_size[0]*i : top_left[0] + patch_size[0]*(i+1)
                    ,top_left[1] + patch_size[1]*j : top_left[1] + patch_size[1]*(j+1)]
```

Then when I try to change the value of each patch, the assignment change the variable value instead of the value the generator gives

```
output_im = np.zeros((patch_size[0]*grid_size[0], patch_size[1]*grid_size[1]))        
output_im_it = extracted_patches(output_im, (0,0), patch_size, grid_size)

for i in xrange(grid_size[0]*grid_size[1]):
    output_im_it = np.random.random(patch_size)
```

Can my generator be mutable?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure because I don't have numpy installed on the computer I am at right now, but you should be able to overwrite the patches in-place by just adding "[:]", something like this:

    for patch in extracted_patches(...):
        patch[:] = np.random.random(patch_size)

Comment: That would be assigning to the generator object. You want to assign to (slices of) the values it yields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with any variables holding a numpy array, to change the value "pointed to" you want to avoid assigning to the variable but assign to a slice of it. Try this:

```
for submat in output_im_it:
     submat[:] = np.random.random(patch_size)
```

As a response to your edit: it seems you have confused the generator object with the values it yields. You can't assign to slices of the generator object itself. You can assign to slices of the numpy arrays, which you can get with e.g. `output_im_it.next()` or with a for loop, as above.

Comment: I get TypeError: 'generator' object does not support item assignment

Comment: Works for me. What exactly are you running? If you try to assign to output_im_it[:], that would give that error message.

Comment: Ah, it works now when I change the for loop as well. Is there a way to not having to change my for loop?

Comment: I guess you could do output_im_it.next()[:] = ... if you wanted to, but it would seem unnecessarily complicated to me.

Comment: Thank you. My for loop is a bit more complicated than the sample I gave so I would prefer to call next() myself.

Comment: If you do need the i variable, `for submat, i in itertools.izip(output_im_it, xrange(...))` would still be IMHO clearer than calling next explicitly -- it puts all the information about what you are iterating over in the for loop.